# Hibernate Option Disappeared

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, hibernate

A while ago I had the option to hibernate the computer. Nowadays, this option disappeared. In fact, even the standby option (when click the turn off button) is greyed out.
I have tried the "powercfg -h on" switch and no success. I'm also missing the hibernation tab in Power options.

My system is Windows XP Home Edition, SP3

In the device manager, I have a yellow exclamation mark near the Video Controller (VGA Compatible), under "Other Devices" but everything else looks normal. Could this be related? If yes, what should I do? If no, what else could it be?

Comment: How much space do you have left on your hard drive? Also, is hybrid sleep enabled in your power plan? In addition, it seems that there are issues going into hiberbation/sleep when drivers have issues. I would fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those options could be related. In particular, to use hibernation or 'suspend' modes, all device drivers must support it. In your case, the driver for the video card has failed to start, and Windows switched back to the generic VGA driver.

Double-click the "Video Controller" item to find out some more information about the failure. What exactly to do next depends on the exact problem; sometimes it's enough to reinstall drivers, other times you have to reinstall the system or even replace hardware.